# angular 4 universal not working properly in IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, angular-universal

sorry for my English skill...
in my angular4 universal project I decided to add IE and other legacy browsers compatibility to my project so i uncommented suggested polyfills in polyfills.js...
but when i run the project on IE I got below error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: 'Proxy' is undefined
ReferenceError: 'Proxy' is undefined
   at a (http://localhost:4400/vendor.fdee72b70101e6abd937.bundle.js:1:443121)
   at s (http://localhost:4400/vendor.fdee72b70101e6abd937.bundle.js:1:443162)
   at l (http://localhost:4400/vendor.fdee72b70101e6abd937.bundle.js:1:443203)
....
```

does anyone have the same problem with that and how can i fix it?

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/proxy-polyfill (if you ever get 'Name' is undefined just look for that specific polyfill and add it into polyfill.ts)

Comment: have you tried an npm install?

Comment: @Z.Bagley I also install this polyfill but i got 
ERROR in polyfills.6f383502fafdbb9cd3b5.bundle.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name (lastRevokeFn) [polyfills.6f383502fafdbb9cd3b5.bundle.js:2606,6]

Comment: @Nick what do you mean? i try install some polyfills like proxy-polyfill or harmony-polyfill or even change ts-loader to babel-loader but none of them do not work...

Comment: I find a lot of these problems can be solved by some variation on deleting the node_modules folder, npm cache verify and npm install.